# React-native - 'while' not exit on comparison

Tags: javascript, react-native

as you can see on the image, i a comparison on values get a wrong result and not break the 'while'.

the 'l' variable keep increasing over and over.

this a react-native file. the image is a screen capture of the debugger and part of the code.

I have not idea why is this happening, please help.

```
var index = 0
while (index < 4 && !this.puedoMoverA(index, posibles[index]), final) {
  index++
}
```

i try another naming, but same issue. when `index=5 and up` the 'while' not exit

[screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/5yzz4.png)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You're running into an infinite loop because `final` is truthy.

In any case, the truth value `final` is evaluated to determine if code inside the loop keep running. *i.e.* `l < 4 && !this.puedoMoverA(i, possible[l])` is never evaluated to make this decision.

Fix by *and*-ing `final` or removing it if it doesn't add to the business rule.

```
while(l < 4 && !this.puedoMoverA(i, possible[l])) {
  l = l + 1;
}
```

Comment: you are absolutely right. i miss place the final variable. thanks a lot.

Answer (score 0):

Here `(!this.puedoMoverA(index, posibles[index]), final)` here `final` always `true` so first you want to remove `final`.

`while (index < 4 && !this.puedoMoverA(index, posibles[index])) {
  index++
}`